# Help clearing confusion in a dangling modifier

Tags: word-request, adverbs

Today, several users on a Facebook group were requesting me to send some materials to them via email. So I thought to assure them and I commented using the following sentence:

> I will send the materials via email to you *personally*.

But no sooner had I written it than I realized it might be interpreted as "The materials will be sent to you via email by me **in person**." which is not what I am trying to convey. Rather I am trying to convey "The materials will be sent to you via email by me **to each of you**."

My next thought was *individually*, but I don't think I am able to use it in the desired way either.

**UPDATE**- I, **myself**, will send **a particular email** to **each of the persons of the group**.

So how should I say the sentence keeping the sense I want to mean? Can it be said using *personally*/*individually*?

Comment: I could not find an appropriate tag. If anybody has any suggestion regarding different tag, please feel free to retag it.

Comment: I think you need to edit the text to clarify whether the distinction you're trying to make is that you'll send a *separate email to each person*, as opposed to a *single group email* sent to everyone at once. Using *personally* simply implies you'll send (one or more) emails ***yourself*** (i.e. - you won't get someone else to send it/them for you). Using *individually* implies you will send multiple emails, one to each person.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Please see update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will send the materials via email to you personally

Is a classic example of a [dangling modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier). It could be interpreted two ways:

> A: I will personally send the materials to you via email
>
> B: I will send the materials to you personally, via email

In case A, the meaning is that "I" will be the one to write the email and click send. In case B, the email will go to directly to the recipient (not to his receptionist).

Other similar constructions include:

> I will send an email **to each of you** personally
>
> I will send an email **to each of you** individually

I.e. I will not send a group email, note that in this case "personally" has the same meaning as individually - whereas in the first scenario it more likely means that the email will not go via the receptionist or some other third party

If you want to stress that the email will not go via a third party you can avoid the ambiguity of "personally" and say:

> I will send an email to you **directly**

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do you mean that you will NOT send one group email to all of the people who requested the materials, but instead send one email to each of them? If so, to my ear, *individually* sounds fine to show that meaning; the alternative would be *separately*.  The meaning would also be quite clear by using the phrase you used in your post, *to each of you*.

*I will send the materials via email to each of you.*

Comment: I will send one email to each of them.

Comment: @Mistu, how about "singularly"? If any, I think this word could satisfy your query, no?

Comment: @Mistu4u Individually works perfectly well in this case. I'm not sure that "to each of you" conveys the meaning you're searching for; if you send one mass group email to everyone, you're still sending it to each of them--but you're not sending it individually.

Comment: @WendiKidd, No, It is not a group email. Same email but different persons, say 5 people, i.e I will send same email 5times 1time for per person.

Comment: @Mistu4u Yes, in that case "individually" means what you want to say.  "To each of you" does not mean that, though. :)